# Shopware - Setting background-image property as the uploaded image

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm currently working in a Shopware project, building cms-blocks/elements and I was wondering if there is a way to set the background-image css property as the uploaded image.

I created a card using CMS-block, a CMS-ELEMENT where you can upload a media file and I just want to link the uploaded media file to the background-image css property. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can add bg image from custom css or try from js

https://store.shopware.com/dne5719820551438f/custom-javascript/css-manager-fuer-shopware-6.html

```
var idCardBg = document.getElementById("idcard");
  idCardBg.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg.jpg')";
```